# Can't find a control for size under physics in the particles panel

Tags: particles

I'm following Andrew's Blender Guru beginner tutorials, and I'm working on particles right now. The problem is I can't find "size" and "random size" options under physics in the particle panel. I can see it on Andrew's tutorial but I can't find it on my own software. [image: Screenshot of my software]

[image: Screenshot of blender in the tutorial]

Comment: maybe https://developer.blender.org/T54003 (try to install 2.79 not 2.79a)

Comment: @lemon It's 2.79 I have installed, u can see it on the screenshot.

Comment: (from the answer in [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102198/1853): Particle Size was "consolidated" under the Render panel in 2.79a

In 2.79, particle size appeared in more than one panel, which caused issues.

See

https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2018-January/103452.html

for more details.

Comment: @SignorCharles, the "a" appears in the splash screen not in the header bar. So have a look at the splash screen

Comment: @cegaton Yes, this was very helpful, I found it nested under the "Render" after unchecking the "Advanced button"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...So I unchecked "Advanced" button under Particles panel and discovered "size" and "random size" controls were nested under "Render" in the same panel. I think that's how it is in my version 2.79 of blender.